# What's Chromium's user agent string?

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent, chromium

What's Chromium's user agent string? Is it same as Chrome's user agent string?

Comment: Not an answer, but just a note, the below answers are true, as well as the fact that Chromium will have an older "outdated" version. I'm actually in the process of investigating how to overcome this right now. Google's websites and some other websites come up with a banner message that my version of Chrome is outdated, although my actual Chrome is up to date. It's the binaries which come with it that matter, as well as configuration.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709218/changing-the-user-agent-in-chromium-embedded-3-dcef3-cefvcl

Comment: You can intercept it and both read the user agent as well as return your own. It's not straight-forward, but it works. Also, when returning a custom user agent string, many websites will get confused as to what browser you're using. For example, Google shows a very generic version of their websites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, Chromium identifies itself as Chrome.

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36

’Course, the operating system and version are probably going to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium now IDs as Chrome/ (Same as Google Chrome)
Very old versions of Chromium ID as Chromium/

Half the browsers now ID as Chrome
and all (or 99%) also ID as Mozilla!

Answer (score -1):

Actually I remember reading that Chromium's version is different from the Chrome browsers and you could use that to distinguish between the two.